# print dictionary element in a list of dictionaries using python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list that contains several dictionaries - The list looks like this:

```
[{'DeltaG': -9.82, 'BasePairs': 4}, {'DeltaG': -9.25, 'BasePairs': 6}, {'DeltaG': -8.96, 'BasePairs': 8}]
```

What I want to do is to print `DeltaG` value if the `BasePairs` == 6 is found. If the `BasePairs` == 6 is NOT found then print the `deltaG` for the first `BasePairs` < 6:

I tried the code below but it gives the DeltaG= -9.82 which is for the first BasePairs == 4 while it should first search if there is BasePiars== 6 first.

```
for tuple in results:
    if float(tuple["BasePairs"]) == 6:  
        deltaG = float(tuple["DeltaG"])
print(deltaG)
    else:
        if float(tuple["BasePairs"]) < 6: 
            deltaG = float(tuple["DeltaG"])
print(deltaG)
```

Anyone can help me with this? Thank you

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your code, you can check something like this:

```
found = False
for tup in results:
    if float(tup["BasePairs"]) < 6 and not found: 
        deltaG = float(tup["DeltaG"])
        found = True
    if float(tup["BasePairs"]) == 6:  
        deltaG = float(tup["DeltaG"])
        break
print(deltaG)
```

Or if you want to use the smaller value:

```
min_base_pairs_val = float('inf')
for tup in results:
    if float(tup["BasePairs"]) < min_base_pairs_val: 
        deltaG = float(tup["DeltaG"])
        min_base_pairs_val = float(tup["BasePairs"])
    if float(tup["BasePairs"]) == 6:  
        deltaG = float(tup["DeltaG"])
        break
print(deltaG)
```

Note, don't use `tuple` as variable name, as it is a function in Python.

Answer (score 2):

You can use next with a default

```
next(
   (i["DeltaG"] for i in results if i["BasePairs"] == 6),
   next(
       (i["DeltaG"] for i in results  if i["BasePairs"] < 6), None
   )
)
```

This searches for the first value in your list of dictionaries that has a base pairs of 6, if it doesnt find any, it returns the first value with a base pair less than 6 (or None if none found)

Comment: If there is no value with 6, OP wants the first value less than 6. Your code simply returns the first value

Comment: @Sayse--great answer, but you have a `SyntaxError: unmatched ')'`

Comment: Although I have provided a different answer, I must admit that this is the best solution and should be the accepted one: elegant, short, effective, perfect. I learned from it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a list comprehension to get all the BasePairs values then I'd look if 6 (`threshold`) is inside it. If yes I can get its index and access the 'DeltaG' value for it otherwise I return the first 'DeltaG' where value < `threshold`.

**Code**:

```
results = [{'DeltaG': -9.82, 'BasePairs': 4}, 
            {'DeltaG': -9.25, 'BasePairs': 6}, 
            {'DeltaG': -8.96, 'BasePairs': 8}]
    
threshold = 6
    
x = [d['BasePairs'] for d in results]

if threshold in x: 
    print(results[x.index(threshold)]['DeltaG'])
else:
    i = 0
    for v in x:
        if v < threshold:
            print(results[x.index(v)]['DeltaG'])
            break
        i +=1
```

**Output**:

```
-9.25
```

Let's try different values. I modified the first 'BasePairs' to 18, then I try different threshold values.

```
results = [{'DeltaG': -9.82, 'BasePairs': 18}, 
            {'DeltaG': -9.25, 'BasePairs': 6}, 
            {'DeltaG': -8.96, 'BasePairs': 2}]

threshold = 8

-9.25

threshold = 5

-8.96
```

Comment: how about the ```print(l[0]['DeltaG'])```? can not this be problematic? sometimes I have BasePairs == 8 in the beginning and I think the last command of your code will consider it, however, I want to print deltaG for the BasePiairs < 6 (if there is not BasePairs ==6)

Comment: Yes, I fixed it